# Adding Dynamic headers to CloudFront

Tags: php, amazon-cloudfront

I am using CloudFront for so people can download content. I have code which signs the url and that works perfectly. I am trying to dynamically set the content-disposition header.

This is an example of what I would like:
http://d3cxc3t3tjxyo3.cloudfront.net/224454/scene/ash_hollywood_delivery_boy_high.mp4?Policy=XX&Signature=XX&Key-Pair-Id=XX&content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3DFilename.mp4